# Cannot add foreign key constraint but IDs exist

Tags: mysql, innodb

I recently updated the foreign key constraints of existing tables with existing records. I'm running into a peculiar error in my join tables. When I create a record on the JOIN tables between two records created before the constraint, everything works fine. When I created a JOIN between a new record, it fails. Any guidance is appreciated!

Here are the logs

```
    LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2021-11-12 03:19:04 0x14c4a54ef700 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 15359185, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 13613, OS thread handle 22834819561216, query id 4697160 174.194.192.130 prisma update
INSERT INTO `_IssuesOnSpace` (`A`, `B`) VALUES ('ckvvk2c4k1376290kmpxyqqz8zo', 'ckd3xy20ecfde0782jsaq5ydr')
Foreign key constraint fails for table `nodafi_backend@production-mirror`.`_IssuesOnSpace`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `_IssuesOnSpace_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`A`) REFERENCES `Issue` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
Trying to add in child table, in index IssuesOnSpace_AB_unique tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 4 fields;
 0: len 25; hex 636b76766b3263346b313337363239306b6d70787971717a38; asc ckvvk2c4k1376290kmpxyqqz8;;
 1: len 25; hex 636b6433787932306563666465303738326a73617135796472; asc ckd3xy20ecfde0782jsaq5ydr;;
 2: len 6; hex 000000ea5cd1; asc     \ ;;
 3: len 7; hex 00000000000000; asc        ;;

But in parent table `nodafi_backend@production-mirror`.`Issue`, in index PRIMARY,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 12; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 30; hex 636b76766b3263346b313337363239306b6d70787971717a387a6f202020; asc ckvvk2c4k1376290kmpxyqqz8zo   ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000ea5c2c; asc     \,;;
 2: len 7; hex c0000004112d16; asc      - ;;
 3: len 12; hex 4e6577657374206973737565; asc Newest issue;;
 4: len 12; hex 4e6577657374206973737565; asc Newest issue;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 5; hex 99ab17705b; asc    p[;;
 7: len 7; hex 99ab181a86253a; asc      %:;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: len 30; hex 636a6a317471796d7a3134343330373636316c30346a7a326b2020202020; asc cjj1tqymz144307661l04jz2k     ;;
 10: len 30; hex 636a6a31747179676f313433783037363632347635713839792020202020; asc cjj1tqygo143x076624v5q89y     ;;
 11: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
```

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE...` queries, some sample data and the query that is failing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.